# Recorrer un array con un bucle FOR

Tags: php, array, loops

Estoy intentado repetir N veces un array con un bucle FOR, pero me he quedado estancado en el último array que contiene más elementos.
Este es mi codigo hasta el momento.

```
$datos = array();
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++) {
    $medidor = 'medidor'.mt_rand(1,99);
    for ($j = 1 ; $j <= 50 ; $j++) {
        for ($k = 0 ; $k < 5 ; $k++) { 
            $datos[$medidor.$i][$j] = array('fecha' => fecha_aleatoria('d/m/Y H:i:s'), 'valor' => mt_rand(1,200));
        }  
    }
}

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) { 
    $centro->insertOne(['nombre' => 'CENTRO-'.mt_rand(1,99), 'datos' => $datos]);
}
```

Necesito repetir 5 veces los valores del array que contiene la fecha y un valor.

```
array('fecha' => fecha_aleatoria('d/m/Y H:i:s'), 'valor' => mt_rand(1,200));
```

Algo así como:

```
Fecha: 05/03/2015
Valor: 25
Fecha: 10/12/2012
Valor: 45
Fecha: 15/06/2005
Valor: 67
Fecha: 26/05/2009
Valor: 78
.
.
.
```

Lo he intentado de muchas maneras, pero no lo consigo. ¿Alguien que me eche una mano a cómo repetir N veces ese array?

EDIT: Para mayor comprensión sobre mi pregunta, esto es lo que obtengo en Robo3T (Administrador Visual de BD NoSQL, en este caso mongodb)
[image: Robo3T]

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tomar en cuenta que estás generando 50 'medidores' (con el bucle de $i)
Cada uno de esos 50 'medidores' tienen 50 datos (generados por el bucle $j),
esos 'datos' son los que contienen la fecha y el valor. El bucle de $k está de más, puesto a que sobrescribe 5 veces un mismo valor de un dato.
Con el último bucle FOR estás creando 50 centros pero estás colocando los mismos datos en todos ellos, a pesar de eso tu información queda así:

```
//50 centros
centroN1 [//50 medidores por cada centro
    medidorN1 [//50 datos por cada medidor
        datosN1{fecha,valor},
        datosN2{fecha,valor},
        ...
        datosN50{fecha,valor}
    ],
    medidorN2 [//50 datos por cada medidor
        datosN1{fecha,valor},
        datosN2{fecha,valor},
        ...
        datosN50{fecha,valor}
    ],
    ...
    medidorN50 [...]
]
centroN2 [//50 medidores por cada centro
    medidorN1 [...],//50 datos por cada medidor
    medidorN2 [...],
    ...
    medidorN50 [...]
]
...
centroN50 [...]
```

Para que cada centro tenga distinta información, lo que puedes hacer es colocar los primeros bucles en una función, y eliminando la variable $k que no hace nada relevante quedaría así:

```
function datos_centro() {
    $datos = array();
    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++) {
        $medidor = 'medidor'.mt_rand(1,99);
        for ($j = 1 ; $j <= 50 ; $j++) {
            $datos[$medidor.$i][$j] = array('fecha' => fecha_aleatoria('d/m/Y H:i:s'), 'valor' => mt_rand(1,200));  
        }
    }
    return $datos;
}
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 2 ; $i++) { 
    $centro->insertOne(['nombre' => 'CENTRO-'.mt_rand(1,99), 'datos' => $datos]);
}
```

Tu código en rasgos generales estaría funcionando y guardando correctamente, para la muestra de esos datos podrías usar una estructura parecida con los FOR o en el caso de que tengas N datos podrías usar foreach dentro de cada 'centro':

```
foreach ($centro->datos as $datos_medidor) {
    echo 'Medidor: '.$i.'<br />'; //muestra el nombre del medidor
    foreach ($datos_medidor as $fecha_valor) {
        //muestra la fecha, pero con el formato 'd/m/Y H:i:s'
        echo 'Fecha: '.$fecha_valor['fecha'].'<br />';
        echo 'Valor: '.$fecha_valor['valor'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Para que la fecha salga con el formato que deseas ('d/m/Y') puedes cambiar el formato en el momento que llamas a insertOne() o al momento de mostrar puedes cortar el string en el último bucle usando explode()

```
foreach ($datos_medidor as $fecha_valor) {
        $fecha = explode(' ', $fecha_valor['fecha'])[0];
        echo 'Fecha: '.$fecha.'<br />';
        echo 'Valor: '.$fecha_valor['valor'].'<br />';
}
```

Deberías detallar más sobre tu problema, para saber si no está registrando los datos como deseas o si el defecto se encuentra en la muestra de los datos

**EDIT**

Aparentemente, lo que quieres es **repetir los mismos valores para la misma magnitud**. Si ese es el caso, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar esto:

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++) {
    $medidor = 'medidor'.mt_rand(1,99);
    for ($j = 1 ; $j <= 50 ; $j++) {
        $datos[$medidor.$i][$j] = array('fecha' => fecha_aleatoria('d/m/Y H:i:s'), 'valor' => mt_rand(1,200));  
    }
}
```

Por esto:

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 50 ; $i++) {
    $medidor = 'medidor'.mt_rand(1,99);
    $fecha = fecha_aleatoria('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    $valor = mt_rand(1,200);
    for ($j = 1 ; $j <= 50 ; $j++) {
    $datos[$medidor.$i][$j] = array('fecha' => $fecha, 'valor' => $valor);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar a mi pregunta. Es cierto que estaba colocando los mismo datos en `fecha` y `valor` , no me habia dado cuenta. Pero el problema persiste en mi codigo, mi pregunta es sobre como hacer un bucle para el array `array('fecha' => fecha_aleatoria('d/m/Y H:i:s'), 'valor' => mt_rand(1,200));`

Comment: Tu problema de encuentra en el registro de los datos, o al momento de mostrarlos? deberías detallar más ese punto, y también si la función insertOne() trabaja correctamente

Comment: El problema lo tengo en la inserccion de datos, es decir, en el REGISTRO de datos. El `insertOne()` trabaja correctamente. Lo único que no logro es repetir N veces el array `array('fecha' => fecha_aleatoria('d/m/Y H:i:s'), 'valor' => mt_rand(1,200));`

Comment: He añadido a la pregunta contenido visual de lo que obtengo al insertar

Comment: Aparentemente el problema va al momento de invocar a los números aleatorios, acabo de añadir esa parte en mi respuesta

Comment: Eso es justo lo que quiero. Pero el código que me has pasado está funcionando igual que el mio.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás usando arreglos tridimencionales sin necesidad, ya que podrias armar un array bidimencional con clave => valor, PERO
Voy a responder tu pregunta en concreto. Quizás los que estás buscando es un `foreach`

```
foreach (expresión_array as $valor)
        sentencias 
foreach (expresión_array as $clave => $valor)
        sentencias
```

Si tu haces:

```
foreach ($datos as $dato) {
//Es aquí donde necesitas el doble loop, recuerda que estás usando un array tridimencional donde cada clave es un entero 
    foreach ($dato as $valor){

        var_dump($valor['fecha']);
        var_dump($valor['valor']);
    }
}
```

//output

```
string(10) "12/03/2018"
int(199)
string(10) "12/03/2018"
int(122)
string(10) "12/03/2018"
int(186)
string(10) "12/03/2018"
int(23)
string(10) "12/03/2018"
int(75)
string(10) "12/03/2018"
int(147)
string(10) "12/03/2018"
int(130)
```

Que es en definitiva lo que tu querías.

Comment: Gracias por contestar a mi pregunta Juan. ¿Dices de poner los 2 FOR dentro del primer foreach?. Aun siendo de esa manera, no sé muy bien como me dices de transformar el código con los foreach.

Comment: Juan Patrono, sigo intentado terminar este código, epero que me puedas contestar a como transformar mi código con los foreach